# How to Automate Execute UPDATE Statement from CONCAT Output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL query for building an `UPDATE` statement with `CONCAT` like this.

**Example:**

```
select top 10000
  concat ('update customer set phone_number = ''',phone_number,
  ''' where id = ''',id,''';')
  from (
    select a.phone_number, c.id from customer c
    join address a on c.id = a.customer_id
    where c.phone_number is null
  ) as cust_phone;
```

**Result:**

```
update customer set phone_number = '628814232154' where id = '3';
update customer set phone_number = '62896631457' where id = '5';
```

Is possible making this UPDATE output to run automatically? I still newbie with SQL Programming.

Comment: Please only tag the relevant database

Comment: In SQL Server you can execute a dynamic SQL string https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and `top` is non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: tag editted. i am using sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why build a string at all?

```
update c set phone_number = a.phone_number
from customer c
join address a on c.id = a.customer_id
where c.phone_number is null
```

If you’re desperate to have the TOP in there:

```
update u set phone_number = t.phone_number
from customer u
join 
(
  select top 10000 c.id, a.phone_number 
  from customer c join address a on c.id = a.customer_id
  where c.phone_number is null
) t 
on u.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

[assuming sql-server]
Your posted code is almost there if you want to go the Dynamic Sql route.  You just need to concatenate the output of your query into a sql string, and execute it with Exec(@sql)

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = @sql + concat ('update customer set phone_number = ''',phone_number,''' 
    where id = ''',id,''';',Char(10))
from (
    select top 10000 a.phone_number, c.id from customer c
    join address a on c.id = a.customer_id
    where c.phone_number is null
) as cust_phone;

Exec(@sql)
```

You will want to move your top n filter into the subquery, as i did above.

Comment: thank you for your answer but how to check the stored query? i want to check it first before execute it.

Comment: @RamadhanRizkiHaryono use `PRINT (@sql)` to check the built query. Although I don't recommend using dynamic SQL for things that can be done in a simple update statement.

Comment: when run that query it return blank page on result.

i can do it manually but i want to put that query on job schedule every day because the record is so many.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
UPDATE customer
SET phone_number = (SELECT phone_number
           FROM address
           WHERE customer.id = address.customer_id)
WHERE phone_number is null;
```